# mongodb pymongo empty when counter > 1

Tags: python, mongodb, cursor, pymongo

I'm trying to do something when count() = 1. I confirmed cursor.count() == 1 by printing it out, but when I use cursor[0], it raised an exception.

```
if not cursor.count():
    return self.create_new_incident(tweet)
elif loc_cur.count() == 1:
    return self.update_existing_incident(tweet, cursor[0])
....

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 588, in __getitem__
    raise IndexError("no such item for Cursor instance")
```

IndexError: no such item for Cursor instance

I read this:
[Using pymongo's ReplicaSetConnection: sometimes getting "IndexError: no such item for Cursor"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060402/using-pymongos-replicasetconnection-sometimes-getting-indexerror-no-such-ite)
I have closed other unused connections, but still not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of `cursor[0]`, you want to be using `cursor.next()` to fetch the next document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PyMongo's [Cursor class](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html) uses an [Iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) concept, so you should use `cursor.next()` to fetch the next document.

If a cursor *hasn't* been created yet (eg. when you are sending the initial `find()` query), you could use a [index](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.__getitem__) to get a single document or slice of documents in the returned cursor.